# CodeRush Xpress Colors

Tags: visual-studio, color-scheme, visual-studio-addins, coderush, coderush-xpress

I downloaded the free CodeRush Xpress version to try it.  Is there a way to change the colors it uses for it's highlighting and line drawing?  ie the matching braces.  I have a dark color scheme and my monitor I have VS on must suck because I can't see the lines.  Yet on the LCD I can.  Is there a way to change the colors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use *CodeRush Xpress 9.2*. It is possible to configure some colors used for highlighting in the Options menu of *CodeRush Xpress*. You can find the menu in *Visual Studio* under *DevExpress* -> *Options*. Go to the *Painting* sub-item of the *Editor* item to control some of the colors used (among them *Navigation Fields*, *Navigation Links* and *Text fields*).

If the *DevExpress* menu doesn't appear in your *Visual Studio* installation, just press `Alt+Ctrl+Shift+O` to directly go to DevExpress Options. Or, if you permanently want the *DevExpress* menu entry in *Visual Studio*, set the following registry key and restart it:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Developer Express\CodeRush for VS\9.2]
    "HideMenu"=dword:00000000
```

This works at least with *Visual Studio 2005* and *2008*.

Answer (score 4):

Just found this online... You can open their control menu with this key combination: ctrl+alt+shift+o

i'm using VS 2008 for the record & CodeRush xpress 9.2. i didnt see a menu in Visual Studio anywhere and i didnt find that registry setting either.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a 64bit machine the path will be different:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Developer Express\CodeRush for VS`